# Normal subgroups of projective special linear group over a ring

Tags: gr.group-theory, reference-request

What are the normal subgroups of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Pick an $n$ and a $p$ and you can ask GAP to list them for you.  Is that all you want -- a list? 

Comment: One can think of some obvious ones; presumably you want to know if these are the only ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's suppose that $p >3$ (otherwise, the groups is solvable in any case). I also work with
$G = {\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})$, but there is an obvious correspondence between
what happens for ${\rm PSL}$ and what happens for ${\rm SL}$. The group $G$ has a largest
normal $p$-subgroup (denoted, as is customary for group theorists, by $O_p(G)$), and
a central subgroup $Z$ of order $2$. $G/Z \times O_{p}(G)$ is isomorphic to the simple group ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. Furthermore, $H = O_{p}(G)$ is the set 
of elements of $G$ which are congruent (entrywise) to the identity $(mod p)$. More generally, we have a series of obvious normal subgroups 
$$ 1 = H_n  <  H_{n-1} < \ldots   < H_{1} = H < G,$$ where $H_{i}$ is the set of elements of $G$  congruent (entrywise) to the identity $(mod p^i)$. For each $j$, $H_{j}/H_{j+1}$ is an elementary Abelian $p$-group (that is, an Abelian $p$-group of exponent $p$).
To see this, note that for $a,b \in H_j$, we have $ab -ba = (a-I)(b-I) - (b-I)(a-I) \equiv 0$ (mod $p^{2j})$, so that $I - a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \equiv 0$ (mod $p^{2j}$). Hence 
$[H_{j},H_{j}] \subseteq H_{2j} \subseteq H_{j+1}$ and $H_{J}/H_{j+1}$ is Abelian
(in fact $H_{j}/H_{2j}$ is Abelian). Also , for $a \in H_j$, we have 
$a^{p} - I = (a-I)(a^{p-1}+ \ldots a^{p-2} + \ldots + I) \equiv 0$ (mod $p^{j+1})$,
so that $a^p \in H_{j+1}$. Each of the factor groups $H_{j}/H_{j+1}$ has the structure
of a module for the group ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ over the field of $p$-elements.

Comment: I guess it should be: "... $H_i$ is the set of elements congruent to the identity $\mod p^i$", and $H= H_1$ in the displayed equation? Alternatively, $H_i$ is the kernel of $ {\rm SL}(2, \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}) \to {\rm SL} (2,\mathbb{Z}/p^i \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I started to write the chain the other way round. Now corrected, I think

Comment: Thanks Geoff. Is it known whether there are any normal subgroups which aren't contained in H?

Comment: I promised to get back to this. A start is that when $n$ is at least $2$, all elements of order $p$ in $G$ actually lie in $H$ ( the idea is that a solution of $x^p \equiv I$ (mod p^2) with $x \not \equiv I$ (mod p) lifts to an element of order $p$ in ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}_{p})$, then its mininum polynomial contradicts the irreducibility of $x^p + \ldots + x +1$.

Comment: @bobgiraffe: For $p>3$, $G={\rm SL}(2, \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$ is perfect, if I remember correctly. (I think this can be shown in a similar way as showing that ${\rm SL}(2, \mathbb{F})$ is perfect for fields with more than 3 elements.) Since the other composition factors of $G$ are abelian, it follows that $H$ is the unique maximal normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @Felix: That's my recollection too, and it certainly does what's necessary, thanks. I hadn't tried to reconstruct the proof. I was going in the direction of thinking that for each $i$, $H_i/H_{i+1}$ is the direct sum of a trivial module and a $3$-dimensional irreducible module for ${\rm SL}(2,p)$, and by my previous remark, 
in $G/H_{i+1}$, every normal subgroup must contain $H_i/H_{i+1}$.

Comment: well, in my last comment, $H\times Z$ (not $H$) is the unique maximal normal subgroup. 

Comment: @Felix and Geoff: Thank you. How about when $p \leq 5$? Looking at the case $p=2$, it looks like if we let $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / 2^n \mathbb{Z}) = G$ (with $n \geq 2$) then $G / [G,G] \cong \mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$. I'm not a group theorist and am struggling to prove this is true, but it seems like it should be known. Could you please offer any thoughts or a reference for this classical theory?

Comment: I think it's $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. I tested it on GAP and get the following: gap> IsCyclic(FactorGroup(SL
(2,Integers mod 2^3),CommutatorSubgroup(SL(2,Integers mod 2^3),SL(2,Integers mod 2^3)))); true I'm new to GAP so I hope I'm not misinterpreting this? It also looks like the coset reps are upper unitriangular with top right entry 0,1,2,-1. – bobgiraffe 0 secs ago

Comment: I was going to suggest that you try GAP (not that I am an expert), but decided against it, since you said you were not a group theorist. I think you are interpreting the output correctly. 

Comment: I've been trying to reduce the problem to something simpler by the following:

 I know it is true for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z})$ and the reduction homomorphism $\phi$ from $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z})$ to $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z})$ is surjective and goes through commutators i.e. $\phi[g,h] = [\phi(g), \phi(h)]$. Now the problem reduces to various things (e.g. I think it would do if $ker(\phi) \subseteq [G,G]$.), but all seem difficult since I can't really get hold of what the commutators look like. 

Comment: @Felix and Geoff: Also, do you have a reference for showing that $SL_
2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$ is perfect for $p\geq5$ 
please? Or any reference where these groups over $\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z}$ for 
$m$ not prime is discussed.

Comment: @bobgiraffe: for $G= SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, $G/[G,G]$ is cyclic of order 12. The group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by two elements of order $m$, so commutator factor group of this group is cyclic of order dividing $gcd(m,12)$. If you know, for example, that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ has factor group $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, then you have an epimorphism $H=SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/2^n \mathbb{Z}) \to SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\geq 2$, which implies $|H/[H,H]|\geq 4$. See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs (the note on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$).